# How to remove empty space after last row when using Can Grow option on text fields in Crystal Report?

Tags: crystal-reports, report, space, autoresize

I have a report displaying rows with text fields with variable length (I use the Can Grow option). I use a Box for the details. My problem is that when the last text field cannot fit into to the box on the bottom of the page, a empty space is left, and the new row begins on next page. Unchecking the option Keep Object Together on the fields, didn't solve the problem and if it did I don't want the content of the text field to break across pages.
My question is: Is it possible to auto-re-size box height depending on rows content, so I can avoid empty spaces at the bottom on every page (doesn't look very nice).
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things I can think of that might help.

1. As you said, you can limit the maximum size of a "can grow" field.  To the right of the can grow checkbox (in CR designer) there is a "Maximum number of lines" value that defaults to 0 (no limit).  You can set that to however many lines you like.
2. The details section itself has a setting for "keep together" too -- right-click the details section label and go to the section expert.  If you uncheck it there the details section will start on the bottom of the page and continue on the next one.
3. Look at the page footer section, it is printed at the bottom of each page, and if it is large, it takes away from the available space for the data.  Group footers, if you have any, could give you the same problem.

Comment: 1.I don't know if my question was clear enough. I don't want the field content to be cut off (with the "Maximum number of lines" option set to a specific length, because I don't know the maximum length of the field's content).
2.Also, I don't want to uncheck rows' "Keep together" option, because it splits the contents in two pages.
3. The page footer is very small, and Yes, I have a group footer, but since it appears on the last page, it doesn't seem to make a problem

Comment: My question is : Is it possible to adjust the box height dynamically, so it doesn't leave an empty row if the field's content of the next row is greater than the space left on the current page.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to adjust it to the right or left, except for centering the text.  Make the field the widest it ever be, and then use the center justify (or right justify) option to have it grow from the center outward (or from the right side to the left).