# Split TextObject Main Report

Tags: crystal-reports

i have a report and in this report i add text object .

[image: Image 1]

in this text object , i insert many value so the report look like this.

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

in the page 2, half of page 2 is empty

because value is long then the value move to page 3

my question is how to split text object with many value? half value in page 2 and hal value again in page 3 , so the page 2 is full, not empty ?

Comment: On the Detail Sections in Section Expert, do you have the "Keep Together" property checked?

Answer (score 0):

you can set auto grow property true. i think below link would be helpful.

[How to remove empty space after last row when using Can Grow option on text fields in Crystal Report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028036/how-to-remove-empty-space-after-last-row-when-using-can-grow-option-on-text-fiel)

Answer (score 0):

In order for the two fields in your Detail section to stay together you will have to check the "Keep Together" property in the Section Expert. Since you have multiple Detail sections, you should do it for all of them. You can also play with the "New Page before" property in the Paging tab if you want each Detail section to start on a new page.